# When Jenkins or Hudson says it can't find files to archive, how do I troubleshoot it?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, archiving

In the job configuration for a Jenkins 1.418 job (older versions are Hudson) on Windows, I am having trouble with "Archive the artifacts". In the box titled "Files to archive" I have

foo/**/Release/Install/App.exe

The error it gives me at configuration time is:

'foo/**/Release/Install/App.exe' doesn't match anything: 'foo' exists but not 'foo/**/Release/Install/App.exe'

Now, if I'm correct, ** is "search all subdirectories" as per ant.  What is odd, is that no matter what I enter it tells me the top level folder exists (foo), but no other folder exists underneath it. Yet when I use the windows explorer to navigate, all my folders exist.

How can I troubleshoot this or fix it?

**Update:** I figured out a technique to troubleshoot - use the workspace browse features in hudson/jenkins to find what is visible and what is not visible. Turns out some directories had file permissions that blocked them being visible inside jenkins/hudson.

Comment: Doesn't it let you continue?  We are archiving a file whose path isn't built out until the job is executed.  I got that same message when configuring the job, but I recall it letting me continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hudson configured to run a batch file, and my folder references were failing because of some errors in the batch files I was using.  This was not a hudson problem, but a batch file problem.  I saw the error and thought it was the problem because it was a reported error, but the real problem was a silent failure in a batch file.